# xamarin is it free to use for commercial purpose?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

It is confusing with licensing about Xamarin.  My Question is "If I develop an application using Xamarin", then can I use for commercial purpose?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask about *free*, I assume you mean the <strike>Indie</strike> Starter edition.

From their [FAQ](http://xamarin.com/faq#q25):

> For developers just getting started with Xamarin, we're introducing Starter edition, a freely-available version that supports device deployment and **app store publishing** for small apps with no third-party native library dependencies and less than 32k of compiled C# code.

*(my highlight)*

Since all editions above the Starter just add to this, then yes, you can use it for commercial purposes.

You should check that FAQ for a lot of other scenarios.

Comment: The Indie version isn't free (like you seem to imply with your first line).

Comment: Sorry, *head-slap* mistake, I was referring to the Starter edition in my head but wrote everything related to the Indie edition.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good news for you.

[Xamarin for Everyone](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/)

You can Visit the Xamarin Store.

[Build C# apps on Android, iOS, Windows, and Mac with Xamarin.(store)](https://store.xamarin.com/)

Xamarin has also launched [Contest: Get Answering on Stack Overflow](https://blog.xamarin.com/contest-get-answering-on-stack-overflow/)

Because of this contest it is going to be easy for the new users to jump into Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your company size (and some other restrictions), yes Xamarin in now free for commercial use. For more, information please see the following links:

- [Mobile Development Made Easy with Visual Studio and Xamarin](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/31/mobile-app-development-made-easy-with-visual-studio-and-xamarin/)
- [Xamarin Pricing](https://store.xamarin.com)