# Is Xamarin free for Visual Studio 2013 Premium?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

We are in a process of doing R&D on Xamarin to convert our existing Windows Phone app to Cross-Platform. Now with the latest changes in Xamarin, we are trying to understand the licencing terms of Xamarin. We are working on Visual Studio 2013 Premium. So, do we get Xamarin for free as part of our Visual Studio 2013 and my company is also having MSDN Premium Subscription.

As per my knowledge Xamarin is free and part of VS 2015 and it is mentioned in lot of places also (https://www.xamarin.com/compare-visual-studio) but i got confused and got a doubt, Is there any dependency on what VS version we are using to get the free Xamarin Business Edition not the Indie (Starter Edition) licence ?

When i try to download the Xamarin it is downloading "vstoolsforxamarin", which is installing VS Community 2015. Kindly provide link to download Xamarin for VS 213.

I'm new to this Xamarin. So, please correct me if i'm wrong in any matter.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.
Kiran

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#As_a_part_of_Microsoft. It is free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xamarin is it free to use for commercial purpose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781007/xamarin-is-it-free-to-use-for-commercial-purpose)

Comment: This question should relative to the visual studio 2013 update 4.  The other question is not duplicate in this case.

Comment: I really confuse too. I already have VS 2013 Pro. I downloaded Xamarin from [download page](https://www.xamarin.com/download) and I got `vstoolsforxamarin.exe`. After run this installer, it try to install VS 2015 community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781007/xamarin-is-it-free-to-use-for-commercial-purpose/36475688#36475688)

Here is a good news for you.

[Xamarin for Everyone](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/)

You can Visit the Xamarin Store.

[Build C# apps on Android, iOS, Windows, and Mac with Xamarin.(store)](https://store.xamarin.com/)

Xamarin has also launched [Contest: Get Answering on Stack Overflow](https://blog.xamarin.com/contest-get-answering-on-stack-overflow/)

Because of this contest it is going to be easy for the new users to jump into Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: so does that mean I can upload my apps to Google playstore with No restrictions ?

Answer (score 0):

From Xamarin's [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/) regarding pricing

> Visual Studio now includes Xamarin
>   As of today, we are including Xamarin in Visual Studio at no extra cost.
>
> Xamarin will be in every edition of Visual Studio, including the
>   widely-available Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free for
>   individual developers, open source projects, academic research,
>   education, and small professional teams. Develop and publish native
>   apps for iOS and Android with C# or F# from directly within Visual
>   Studio with no limits on app size.
>
> For developers on the Mac, Xamarin Studio is now available as a
>   benefit of your Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise subscription.
>   Developers can use the newly-created Xamarin Studio Community Edition
>   for free.
>
> To begin developing iOS and Android apps with the full power of
>   Xamarin and C#, download Xamarin Studio or Xamarin for Visual Studio
>   today.

From Xamarin's [FAQ](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#q15) regarding Visual Studio Compatibility

> What are the minimum system requirements?
>   Xamarin requires the platform SDKs from Apple and Google to target iOS or Android, and our system requirements match theirs. To build for iOS, you'll need the latest iOS SDK (currently iOS 9.1), which ships with Xcode 7.1 and requires Mac OSX 10.10.5+ (Yosemite) or 10.11 (El Capitan). Our Visual Studio Extensions for iOS and Android support any non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013, and Visual Studio 2015 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.